# How to avoid multiple system entry

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display and insert random number with auto increment number of SQL in a form
like `yy-dd-auto-increment` value.

My problem is if I use two system for inserting the details at a time then it is inserting same auto increment.

Comment: Then add a `UNIQUE` index on the table and retry if the insert fails

Comment: Do you generate the "auto increment" value by hand and then pass it to MySQL or insert in the DB first and then use the generated value?

Comment: Why do you need a random number?  The best thing to do is not use a random number... simply use an auto increment field.  This gives you guaranteed reliability, and allows you to set up replication later, if needed.  If you just need a pseudo-random value for display, that can be done based on a non-random key.